# Giving the password of the server within the command?

Tags: django, rsync

Is it possible to give the server password within the rsync command?

```
rsync -zvr source destination password
```

I am developing a web application in Django using rsync protocol. I use a form to take password input from the user. I want to use that password like this in the rsync command itself? How can I do it? I am sure there's a way using stdin, pipe or something like that. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `rsync -zvr source username:password@destination`?  Just curious.

Comment: Sure did. I tried that at first.

Answer (score 3):

From `man rsync`:

> Some modules on the remote daemon may require authentication. If so, you will receive a password prompt when you connect. You can avoid the password prompt by  setting  the environment variable `RSYNC_PASSWORD` to the password you want to use or using the `--password-file` option. This may be useful when scripting rsync.

And regarding `--password-file`:

> This option allows you to provide a password in a file for accessing a remote rsync daemon. Note that this option is only useful when  accessing  an rsync  daemon  using  the built in transport, not when using a remote shell as the transport. The file must not be world readable. It should contain just the password as a single line.

So, either set the `RSYNC_PASSWORD` environment variable before calling `rsync`, or use a temporary file and pass it to the command; The first option is probably easier, using `env`:

```
env RSYNC_PASSWORD=PASSWORD rsync -zvr source destination
```

---

**Update:** Note this little nugget under `--password-file`:

> Note that this option is only useful when  accessing  an rsync  daemon  using  the built in transport, **not** when using a remote shell as the transport.

If you're not using the `rsync` built-in transport, but perhaps SSH, you cannot use this method to "automatically" authenticate. If you're using SSH, you should use public/private keys, or possibly the `ASK_SSHPASS` trick (See [this](http://andre.frimberger.de/index.php/linux/reading-ssh-password-from-stdin-the-openssh-5-6p1-compatible-way/)).

Comment: I set the environment variable using export $RSYNC_PASSWORD=mypassword and ran the command. No luck though. Still asks password.

Comment: It should be `export RSYNC_PASSWORD=mypassword` without the dollar sign

Comment: Done! The command I used is: RSYNC_PASSWORD="password"; rsync -zvr username@:upload/ /home/hey 
Still asks password!

Comment: Either remove the semicolon, use env or use export.

Comment: Done that. Still asks for the password!

Comment: Please see my edit. I suspect you're using ssh as the underlying transport layer, in which case that's what you have to "worry" about...

Comment: By default rsync uses ssh. How can I use rsync build-in transport? public/private key for shh is too much hassle.

Comment: Did you see my "See this" regarding passing passwords by stdin to SSH, http://andre.frimberger.de/index.php/linux/reading-ssh-password-from-stdin-the-openssh-5-6p1-compatible-way/ ? How to use the built-in rsync daemon is really a different question.